# Analyzer for '&' and 'and'

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I want to build a search on ElasticSearch, but I get stuck with this:

Query for:

- H and M
- H&M
- H & M

Need to find a document with this variable value:

- H&M

How to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [Pattern Replace Char Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html) and append this to your analyzer.

For instance, this would be minimal reproduction:

```
POST /hm
{
  "index": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "my_pattern": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "(\\s+)?&(\\s+)?|(\\s+)?and(\\s+)?",
          "replacement": "and"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "custom_with_char_filter": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "my_pattern"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It will replace `&`, `and` with optional multiple whitespaces around to `and`. So now you can check how this analyzer works by running these statements:

```
GET /hm/_analyze?analyzer=custom_with_char_filter&text=h%26m
GET /hm/_analyze?analyzer=custom_with_char_filter&text=h %26 m
GET /hm/_analyze?analyzer=custom_with_char_filter&text=handm
```

All of these bring back very same token:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "handm",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Which means that whenever you're searching for any of these:

- HandM
- H and M
- H&M
- H & M

It will bring same result.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! Additional problem: I can't use a search analyzer, because I use fuzzy search (H&M~) and they are don't analyzed by default. So I need to create an index analyzer? Or you see other possibilities?

Comment: I think you still could use what I've given and then use [match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzzy-match-query.html) query with `fuzziness`. What do you think? Match query can use analyzed fields.